# HTML tables- side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

I have been helping a friend of mine by editing his HTML code. I am also still a newbie so I am not sure what is going on in terms of tags and structure.

It seems unecessairly complicated but I was wondering whether the following piece of code for two tables could be put side-by-side instead of appearing one above the other?

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <table group_name="Small left image box 2" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;" class="padding"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:580px;" class="padded" align="center">
          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 5px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="5" border="0"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:580px;" class="padded" align="center">
                  <table class="two-col" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:580px;">
                          <table class="columns" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; width:580px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;">

                                  <table block_name="Left Column" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:188px;" class="column">
                                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:180px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                              </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" height="282">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:288px;" class="column" align="left" height="282">

                                                  <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" item_name="Text">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 7px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="7" border="0"></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 2px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" border="0"></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:2px;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal">
                                                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0"></td>
                                                              </tr>

                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded" align="center">
                                                                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/img4_280.jpg" width="280" height="282" alt="Alt Text" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; display:inline;" border="0"></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>

                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td tiny_name="Title" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="center">
                                                                  LOREM IPSUM
                                                                  <br>DOLOR
                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>

                                                              <tr tiny_name="Divider Image" class="<!-- tiny{onlydesktop}[type=mobile] -->onlydesktop">
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; width:280px; font-size:0; line-height:1px; height: 1px; vertical-align: top" class="padded" align="center">
                                                                  <img style="font-size:0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/line_black.png" width="121" height="30" border="0" alt="Alt Text" class="">
                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:180px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                              <!-- /tiny -->

                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td tiny_name="Text" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="center">
                                                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur adipisici elit, <br> tempor inc idunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>

                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0"></td>
                                                              </tr>


                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td width="20" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; width: 20px; height: 30px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="20" height="30" border="0"></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                          </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                      </tr>

                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 30px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" border="0"></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:2px;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 2px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" border="0"></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>

                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>

                                  <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;vertical-align:top;" >
                    <![endif]-->
                    
                                  <table block_name="Right Column" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:580px;" class="padded" align="center" height="282">
                                          <table class="two-col" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:580px;">
                                                  <table class="columns" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; width:580px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;">

                                                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" height="282">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:288px;" class="column" align="left" height="282">

                                                                  <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" item_name="Text">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                      <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="5" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 7px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="7" border="0"></td>
                                                                      </tr>

                                                                      <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal">
                                                                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0"></td>
                                                                              </tr>

                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded" align="center">
                                                                                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/img4_280.jpg" width="280" height="282" alt="Alt Text" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; display:inline;"
                                                                                      border="0"></a>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                              </tr>

                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:180px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                              <!-- /tiny -->

                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td tiny_name="Text" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="left">
                                                                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, tempor inc <br> idunt ut labore et dolore <br> magna aliqua.
                                                                                </td>
                                                                              </tr>

                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0"></td>
                                                                              </tr>

                                                                              <tr tiny_name="Call to action">
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal" align="left">
                                                                                  <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#353535">
                                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                                      <tr>
                                                                                        <td width="20" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; width: 20px; height: 30px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="20" height="30" border="0"></td>
                                                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:middle; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; color:#ffffff;" class="button" align="center">
                                                                                          <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; color:#ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
                                                                                            LOREM SIT
                                                                                          </a>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        <td width="20" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; width: 20px; height: 30px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="20" height="30" border="0"></td>
                                                                                      </tr>
                                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                                  </table>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                              </tr>

                                                                              <tr>
                                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 30px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" border="0"></td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                          </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                                                      </tr>

                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                  </table>

                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                          </table>

                                                          <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;vertical-align:top;" >
                    <![endif]-->

                                                          <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:288px;" class="column" align="right">

                                                                  <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" item_name="Image">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                      <tr>
                                                                        <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                                                      </tr>

                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                  </table>

                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                          </table>

                                                        </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;" class="padding"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;" class="padding"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:580px;" class="padded"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 10px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
                                <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:10px;" class="padding"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/img/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" border="0"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*...for two tables...*" - i counted 18 tables. If you just want two it's indeed complicated. "*...whether the following piece of code ... could be put side-by-side...*" -> Do you mean that the two tables could be put side by side?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use table tag repeats, use screen grid system.

You can divide screen using columns.

Please use following code. just copy and paste.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded" align="center">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/img4_280.jpg" width="280" height="282" alt="Alt Text" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; display:inline;" border="0"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td tiny_name="Title" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="center">
                LOREM IPSUM
                <br>DOLOR
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr tiny_name="Divider Image" class="<!-- tiny{onlydesktop}[type=mobile] -->onlydesktop">
              <td style="padding: 0px; width:280px; font-size:0; line-height:1px; height: 1px; vertical-align: top" class="padded" align="center">
                <img style="font-size:0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/line_black.png" width="121" height="30" border="0" alt="Alt Text" class="">
              </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td tiny_name="Text" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur adipisici elit, <br> tempor inc idunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px;" class="padded-internal"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 20px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" border="0"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="20" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top;"><img style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; width: 20px; height: 30px;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/spacer.gif" width="20" height="30" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align:top; width:280px;" class="padded" align="center">
                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/img4_280.jpg" width="280" height="282" alt="Alt Text" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; display:inline;" border="0"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td tiny_name="Title" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="center">
                LOREM IPSUM
                <br>DOLOR
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr tiny_name="Divider Image" class="<!-- tiny{onlydesktop}[type=mobile] -->onlydesktop">
              <td style="padding: 0px; width:280px; font-size:0; line-height:1px; height: 1px; vertical-align: top" class="padded" align="center">
                <img style="font-size:0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;" src="http://static.contactlab.it/maison_contactLab/pb/20160505/images/line_black.png" width="121" height="30" border="0" alt="Alt Text" class="">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- /tiny -->
            <tr>
              <td tiny_name="Text" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:top; width:256px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#595959;" class="padded-internal" align="center">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur adipisici elit, <br> tempor inc idunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Try to learn CSS.